# C++ - Multithreading

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)(kpts.size()); i++) {
    perform_operation(kpts1[i], *kpts2[i]);
}
```

where `kpt1` and `kpt2` are a `std::vector<>` types. The function `perform_operation` takes `kpt1[i]`, performs an operation on it and stores it in `kpt2[i]`.

It seems like I should be able to multithread this. Since each cycle of the for loop is independent of one another, then I should be able to run this parallely with as many processes as there are `CPU` cores, right?

I've seem several SO questions *kinda* answering this, but they don't really get at how to parallelize a simple for loop; and I'm not sure if reading the same `kpt1` variable and writing to the same `kpt2` variable is possible.

Or am I misunderstanding something? - is this not parallelizable?

I'd be happy if I could find a solution in `C++` or `C`, but right now I am stuck.

Comment: Yes, you can parellelize this trivially, but think a bit beforehand -- surely you don't want thousands of threads, but only as many as yu have physical cores. So you really just want to partition the index space.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is Boost Threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415994/boost-thread-tutorials

Comment: C++11 has support for threads in the standard library.  If `kpts.size()` is large and/or `perform_operation()` is very expensive then it might be worth parallelizing.

Comment: @KerrekSB I will definitely partition `kpts1` so that the max number of threads equals the cores (I'm still deciding which AWS instance I will be using, so I don't know the max cores at the moment). But for argument, lets say I want to split this up into `8` processes. How could I do that?

Comment: Here's a tutorial for C++11 threads http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Provided each `perform_operation` operates independently of each other, then ues, this is parallelizable.

Rather than simply calling perform_operation, start a new thread (with `pthread_create`). You will need to wrap the parameters in a single `struct` (could just be pointers to both arguments), and pass `start_routine` as a wrapper around `perform_operation`. That will create the relevant number of threads. Then in a second `for` loop use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads you have created to exit.

That's a rough outline. Obviously some error handling would be useful, and you might want each thread to perform a number of `perform_operation`s serially, rather than one thread per item. But you should get the basic idea from the above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abligh. This looks like a good approach; but it's exactly the type of example I haven't been able to find any basic code for. I'm very very new to `C/C++` threading, so I'm looking to follow some basic code if possible.

Comment: If you can find a C++ library, that might be easier. If using pthreads, try this: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining - also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376908/how-to-parallelize-monte-carlo-estimation-of-pi-using-pthreads

Comment: @Brett Note that you don't have to use `pthreads` directly in this day and age. C++11 has a threading library, and if you don't have C++11, then there's `boost.thread`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking can you operate on each element of the array in a separate thread?

You can. There are several considerations though.

As long as the separate operations don't impact each other it's a good candidate for parallelism.

As a practical matter standard on CPU threading is slow to setup and eats up a good amount of memory (pthread by default allocates 32 megabytes per thread for the stack). If the tasks are pretty intensive then you get back the setup overhead in time savings. If not then it's both harder to code, bigger, and slower than doing it in a straight forward way.

[Intel TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) is one option. [NVidia CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/about-cuda) is another